# I want to know about Ubuntu basics: shell, command  etc about Ubuntu. help!

Tags: repository, command-line

I'm new to Ubuntu and I want to know some basics about Ubuntu/Linux, because I don't understand command line, shell, etc. Would anyone please explain about ubuntu shell, command and what's the meaning of ppa and repositories in applications package?. I'd be glad if you want to answer my question here or to ferradellia@gmail.com.
I love ubuntu since 3 days ago when I migrated a new operating system to linux and I think Ubuntu is the best for beginners like me. But I have to learn more about linux cuz this one is so different and more fun than Windows.
Thx...Thx!

Answer (score 3):

The [Ubuntu Manual project](http://ubuntu-manual.org/) covers what you want to know and much more, all in an easy language with lots of screenshots.

Answer (score 1):

There are wonderful resources available on the web, specially in Youtube.com search for the term "ubuntu tutorials for beginners"

Videos by NixiePixel are highly recommended.

Another great resource is http://showmedo.com/ teaches you step by step most major open source programs, including Ubuntu. Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

Since Ubuntu is a beginner freindly Linux Distribution, there is plethora of resources available for answering your question, First I suggest you read the Ubuntu User Guide [here](http://ubuntuguide.org/wiki/Ubuntu%3aMaverick)

You can look through the Index of the book and find answers for the specific questions you have. But I recommend for you to read the book cover to cover if you can.

OR

You can Google each of your questions and it will show you how often a variation of your question or the exact same question been answered before.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

My main suggestion sounds silly but it worked/still works for me: Break things! Seriously, try things out and if your set-up gets broken be prepared to start over. You'll learn a lot in this fashion.

Also:

- Open up a terminal and read the `man pages` of various commands e.g. type `man mount` and thoroughly read it. `man pages` are full of good information.
- Take a look at [tuxfiles](http://www.tuxfiles.org/). In particular, read through the tutorials on things like /etc/fstab and APT.
- Try and grasp what each part of a command is meant to do before you issue it. If you don't know, then read the `man page`.
- Search around on [ubuntuforums](http://ubuntuforums.org) and on here and also [unix.stackexchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com).
- Install lots of software and play around.

Most of all, have fun!

Answer (score 0):

I am a bit old school so I stick with books. The way I moved to command line it was this book: [http://www.amazon.com/Ubuntu-Linux-Toolbox-Commands-Debian/dp/0470082933/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1303294691&sr=8-1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0470082933) which provides a clear way how ubuntu is structured and examples that can cover from the novice to advanced user. I read it once to get an idea and run some examples and now I just use it as a reference since its organized in chapters according to the tasks you want to do.

Don't worry about the ubuntu version terminal in the back end is the same.

In cases that internet not available to your server environment (been there), a book is always the solution.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the good suggestions already here about resources specific to Ubuntu, I recommend [The Linux Documentation Project](http://tldp.org/), which has a lot of good resources. In particular, to start, try [Introduction to Linux - A Hands on Guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/intro-linux/html/index.html).